# Add column on table with value dependent on foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm not sure if there is already an answer for this but I didn't manage to find anything.
I have a table named Offer with a primary key ID and another column let's say Mask.

Offer -->

```
    ID  Mask 
    1    0
    2    1
    3    0
```

Let's say I have a completely different table Production that has a column-foreign key Offer_ID that references to the ID of table Offer.
 I want to add a column Mask that will obtain the Mask value of the Offer row that the foreign key references to.

For example:

Production-->

```
    ColA  ColB  Offer_ID    Mask
     ..    ..     1       Here I want 0
```

EDIT:

The table Offers exists and so do its columns ID and Mask.Table Productions also exists,so does the column Offer_ID and is a foreign key to ID of tables Offers.I want to add a column Mask and set its values according to the Offer_ID column value.

The point is I don't want just to set the values properly,but I want whenever a new row is inserted to Productions the Mask column to get a value same with that of the row that foreign key(Offer_ID) references to.

Comment: Hi. This is easily googled if you would phrase your question clearly & concisely many ways. Or if you read *anything* about FKs. You want a "composite FK". PS What do you mean "set a its values according to" & "get a value"? Do you mean *required to have* a value?

Answer (score 1):

You could join the two tables:

```
SELECT p.cola, p.colb, p.offer_id, o.mask
FROM   production p
JOIN   offer o ON p.offer_id = o.id
```

Comment: I want to add the column mask and this column to "point" on the values of offer_mask where o.id=p.offer_id,not to take its values.

Comment: what do you mean with "point" on the values and with "take its values" ?

Comment: The table Offers exists and so do its columns ID and Mask.Table Productions also exists,so does the column Offer_ID and is a foreign key to ID of tables Offers.I want to add a column Mask and set its values according to the Offer_ID column value.